# Set IsVisible property by a string value of model

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am using XAML to define a ListView, with multiple buttons for each cell.
I want to trigger visibility depending on whether a string value is empty or not.
My button inside the ListView is:

```xml
<Button Text="{Binding Phone}" 
        Clicked="OnPhoneClicked"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Telefono}"
        x:Name="btnPhone" />
```

Binding `Phone` is read from my model. It is correctly shown.

How can set a `IsVisible` property button if `Phone`'s value is an empty string?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
<Button Text="{Binding Phone}" 
    Clicked="OnPhoneClicked"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Telefono}"
    x:Name="btnPhone"
    IsVisible="{Binding Phone,Converter={StaticResource StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter"} />
```

StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter.cs file

```
public class StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = value as string;
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Finally add this in `App.xaml` file

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Converter:StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter x:Key="StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Need I to create a  new class  StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter and index it on xaml header?

Comment: Yeah need to create new .cs file somewhere in your project.

Comment: Tx. I am trying your solution. I have an error "StaticResource not found for key StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter" when I put x:local= "myproject.Utils" on the header and using IsVisible="{Binding Mail, Converter={StaticResource StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter} }"

Comment: @doxsi - I have updated my answer please check it once. Make your class names `StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter` only to avoid confusion.